# OPenFDA API - querying on dosage_and_administration_table _exists_ not working

Tags: data.gov, api, openfda, json

I was planning to get the results where brand name is aspirin and whose drug result has property `dosage_and_administration_table`.

So I did this

```
https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=brand_name:aspirin+AND+_exists_:dosage_and_administration_table&limit=100
```

It returns no results (no matches found). But there are results where `dosage_and_administration_table` exists. And one more interesting thing is `_exists_` works with every other parameter like `active_ingredient`, `dosage_and_administration` etc., but not with `dosage_and_administration_table`.

What's wrong with the query?

Comment: This is unhelpful, but I'm guessing the table is actually an SQL join, and The FDA's interface isn't handling it correctly. You get the same problem for "precautions_table" and "pharmacokinetics_table" and "adverse_reactions_table". (note to self: cross off bucket list: use "pharmacokinetics" in a stackexchange post)

Comment: openFDA is in Elasticsearch; there's no SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked at the openFDA code: it appears `dosage_and_administration_table` element is explicitly excluded from indexing in Elasticsearch along with a bunch of other `table` elements, which is why you can't query on it, but still are able to see it in some search results.

I'll need to go back to the team to understand why `dosage_and_administration_table` is being excluded from indexing; most likely because it contains HTML markup and is redundant to the `dosage_and_administration` element. In the meantime, I'd recommend that you use `dosage_and_administration` in your `_exists_` clause.

Comment: Thank you denis. But i want that Html representation only instead of blob of text as in dosage_and_administration.Look like **dosage_and_administration** and **dosage_and_administration_table** are not duplicates